# Unable to fetch the data from Core Data file

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

when I fetch the record from core data it returns null value...i don't know what is the problem...

When I check in `NSLog` it shows like this:

```
"<Ad: 0x979fb30> (entity: Ad; id: 0x9799470 <x-coredata://B3AA111F-8307-4A16-B898-
403A804DFDFB/Ad/p22> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ad: 0x979fd70> (entity: Ad; id: 0x9799480 <x-coredata://B3AA111F-8307-4A16-B898-
403A804DFDFB/Ad/p23> ; data: <fault>)
```

Here is my code.
I returned all the core data functions in separate class called dbmanager.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
DBManager *manager=[[DBManager alloc]init];
self.fetchedRecordsArray = [manager fetchAllAds];
[self.shoppingtbl reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.fetchedRecordsArray count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShoppingCart";
ShoppingCart *cell = (ShoppingCart*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
ad=[self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
cell.addesc.text = ad.data;
cell.adId.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (long)[ad.adId integerValue]];
cell.adstatus.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ad.state];
return cell;
}
```

The entity name called Ad. It contains Adid,state,data.

In table view it shows null value for strings and 0 for numbers..

Comment: What's in self.fetchedRecordsArray in viewDidLoad? Can you NSLog it? Also, why don't you use an NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: when i check in Nslog it shows like this   "<Ad: 0x9a5b350> (entity: Ad; id: 0x9a5a6c0 <x-coredata://B3AA111F-8307-4A16-B898-403A804DFDFB/Ad/p22> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Ad: 0x9a5b590> (entity: Ad; id: 0x9a5a6d0 <x-coredata://B3AA111F-8307-4A16-B898-403A804DFDFB/Ad/p23> ; data: <fault>)"

Comment: Please, update the question to include the content of -[DBManager fetchAllAds]. This is probably a problem with the core data context.   Core Data is a complex subject, I recommend you to check Apple sample data and some open source project to see how to use it properly. There are _tons_ of tutorials out there.

Comment: Note that there is nothing wrong with the `Ad` managed object being faulted. This is normal core data behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you abandon your `fetchedRecordsArray` and embrace the `NSFetchedResultsController`. It is specifically designed to work with core data and table views.

This will almost certainly eliminate the problem you have and result in much more robust and scalable code. You could be displaying 100.000s ads this way without any problem.

One more hint, i.e. something you might want to check beforehand: quite possibly you did not save the data correctly. It looks like you saved each record with `[managedObjectContext save:&error]` after it was created, but perhaps you did not do this correctly after populating it with state, data. The way to check this is to *enumerate* your array elements and `NSLog` those bits of information to check if they are there.

Comment: hi you are almost correct...i am using [managedObjectContext save:&error] to save the record.instead of using this method.there is any other method to save the record?

Comment: Method is correct - the problem might be in what **state** your context is in. If my answer is helpful, please start by up-voting it.